# Pasteable div: paste disappear in context-menu, work only by ctrl+V

Tags: javascript, html, browser, contextmenu, copy-paste

I have HTML div which I make it pasteable-area by the following:

```
$('#' + pasteZoneId).bind("paste", (e)=> {
```

All work well when user press ctrl+v, the event is fired.
The problem is that when user right-click for paste by context menu - paste option disappear in the context-menu.

What should I do?

---

UPDATE:

more details: I don't mean that user can paste things in the div, like text, etc. The div is not really pasteable; I catch the paste event and then have ,y logic, and let paste only images. **I** take the image, **I** attach it to the div by Jquery; not the browser.

Now the question in only how can I cause the context menu to display the 'paste' option, as when user press ctrl+V it works well, the event is fired and the image is attached by my code, so I only want to let user **click** paste instead of **press** paste.

Comment: Attaching an event won't make your element a *pasteable-area*. It needs to be either an input or textarea, or contentEditable.

Answer (score 2):

While every Element can receive a *paste* Event, this Event will always get ignored (as in no default behavior), except if the Element is either an `<input>`,  a `<textarea>`, or in a *contentEditable* mode.

So while there is no specs about what a browser should show in their context-menu, it's a fact that most of them do not show "Paste" where it will get ignored anyway.

So to get it on your `<div>`, you'd have to have its `contentEditable` attribute set to true.

If you don't want it always, you can hack something in the *mousedown* event:

```js
target.onmousedown = e => {
  if (e.button === 2) target.contentEditable = true;
  // wait just enough for 'contextmenu' to fire
  setTimeout(() => target.contentEditable = false, 20);
};

target.onpaste = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('got paste data:', e.clipboardData.getData('text'));
};
```

```html
<div id="target">right click me</div>
```

Comment: This does not work on 2022 browsers ;(

Comment: @giox069 thanks for the heads up, I'll have a look at this tomorrow and update.

Comment: @giox069 so I just tried in all 3 stable major browsers, in their latest stable version and it does work in all of them (macOs).  Which browser did this fail on and which OS?

Comment: I tested the code snipped on Linux (it works) and on windows 11: under windows 11 it does not work with both Firefox and Chrome, on a couple of different PC. The menu without "Paste" is shown.
It seems that changing from 20 to 30ms of timeout solves the problem, but I can't do too much testing this week.

Answer (score 1):

Bind and Unbind is depricated Please use [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Try this

```js
var pasteZoneId="pasteZoneId";
$("#" + pasteZoneId).on("paste", (e)=> {
    alert("Pasting...");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="pasteZoneId">

</textarea>
```

You can also use this with div  like as follows

```js
var pasteZoneId="pasteZoneId";
$("#" + pasteZoneId).on("paste", (e)=> {
    alert("Pasting...");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pasteZoneId" contenteditable style="border:1px solid #000">

</div>
```

Comment: Notice you used textarea element, and I need to use div element (I want to let user paste images, so on paste event I attached the copied image to the div). Any other idea that work in div also?

Comment: Check now my another script it is working with div as well

Comment: work, but not match to my goal, I only want to fire paste event, not really make the div pasteable and not let user change the content of div by adding test... The only what I do is let uset copy image, and then get 'paste' option in the context-menu, and then0- click it will only fire 'paste' event.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `bind`, but make an *event listener*:

```
$("#" + pasteZoneId).on("paste", (e)=> {
    //Function here
});
```